# Ubuntu doesn't boot in dual-boot UEFI mode

Tags: 14.04, windows

My question is, how do I know that I have to disable secure boot or turn legacy mode on before installing Ubuntu on a laptop running windows 8.1 .

As I installed Ubuntu on two different laptops (Lenovo and HP) the Lenovo works correctly and shows:

1. Ubuntu
2. Advanced options for Ubuntu
3. Windows etc.

On the HP, it didn't give any option to choose from and automatically loaded Windows. So, to boot into Ubuntu, I have to Restart the machine by first booting into Windows and then using Shift+Restart (advanced option etc.)

So, my question is: how to decide what to enable and/or disable before installing Ubuntu along Windows 8.1.

Comment: You should not have to do either, you have to select the os to boot in your bios. Ubuntu will boot with secure boot and (U)efi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once upon a time, in the not so far past, *Ubuntu did not support UEFI BOOT* but ***nowadays, Ubuntu supports UEFI BOOT!***

*However* you need to use the UEFI menu to boot the CD, not the BIOS menu...

**Note:** As I have seen UEFI systems that did not support UEFI DEV boot, you had to go into the BIOS to BOOT from DEV, *but that turns UEFI off!*

So if you went into the BIOS of the HP to boot from DVD, what happened was:

- UEFI turned off
- Ubuntu installed in non-UEFI mode
- reboot into UEFI
- Ubuntu doesn't work until you turn off UEFI in the BIOS again. (But to boot Windows 8.1 you need to turn it back on!)

To avoid this for now and in the future, re-install using the UEFI menu to boot the CD, and as I all the HPs I've ever seen all supported UEFI DVD boot, you *might* have an old UEFI firmware on your HP <sub>(Just an informed guess)</sub>, so upgrade your UEFI firmware before reinstalling.

Before upgrading your UEFI firmware, gave a good look through all the UEFI screens as the DVD boot might be hidden away in "advanced settings"..

Comment: Please don't thank me. Just click the grey **☑** under the "1" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid" so that other people then you can find a valid and approved answer (and it'll make your reputation go up as well!)!  ;-)